# is it possible to read a string inside a system.out.println in java

Tags: java, string

is there a way to read the following string inside the print statement?

**i need to make something like the following code**

here is my code:

```
 BufferedReader inl = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
 String mail;
 System.out.println( "MAIL FROM " + "<" + mail = inl.readLine() + ">" );'
```

so when i run the program to show something like `MAIL FROM < HERE I FILL THE STRING>`

Comment: Surround `mail = inl.readLine()` with parentheses: `(mail = inl.readLine())`

Comment: thanks, i made a small edit in my post, check it out

Answer (score 0):

If you use System.setOut, you can re-direct this stream to your own PrintStream, where you can log the messages being sent to System.out, or send these messages wherever they need to go.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setOut(java.io.PrintStream)

Comment: sounds good. i  cant find the synstax of system.setOut. can you write it here please

Comment: @04k https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/system_setout.htm